# How can I convert char to int in c++ to get correct values of numbers?

Tags: c++, char, int

I want to convert `char` to `int` in c++, I used `char a1` and to convert `(int)a1` but I got wrong values, for example:
if a1 is `'1'` then `49`
if a1 is `'2'` then `50`
etc...
Why is this? How can I resolve this?

Comment: There is nothing wrong. Character `'1'` is equal to 49 according to the ASCII standard. See a unicode table [here](http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html#x0000). Look up where it says 49, you'll see it corresponds to the character `'1'`. Similarly, character `'a'` is equal to 97, character `'A'` is 65, and so on.

Comment: Ok, then how can I get from '1' 1 integer?

Comment: Subtract the character `'0'` : `'1'` - `'0'` = 49 - 48 = 1. Works for all characters ranging from `'0'` to `'9'`.

Comment: Please post an [MCVE]

Comment: @AnthonyD. I would advise against using magic constants in your code. `'1' - '0'` works just as fine, but is more readable.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius True, true. I will edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get real value subtract the initial value 
like

```
char x='1'; //ascii value=49
int xx=x-'0' //49-48==1

char a='C'; //67
char aa=a-'A' //67-65=2 means third char of Alphabet
```

or you can type cast to get exact value
Hope you get the idea.

Comment: The first one works for all character encodings; both C and C++ require that the character representations for the digits `'0'` Through `'9'` be contiguous and increasing. The second one is not guaranteed to work, and there are character sets (I'm looking at you, EBCDIC) for which it does not work.

Comment: Ohh  didn't knew about  "EBCDIC" thank you for the info. But in general cases its work cause 0-9, a-z, A-Z are continuous in ASCII encoding

Answer (score 3):

`int atoi (const char * str)`   this function can be helpful in this regard. See the documentation here [atoi() c++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/)

Answer (score 1):

It's because `(int)a` converts just type but not the value. Literally, it says to compiler 'treat value of `a` as an `int` value' which in case of '1' returns its ASCII code 49.
To translate the actual value you can use:

```
// num == 49 - 48; 
int num = (int)a - (int)'0';
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `char` values are usually encoded in ASCII. This means that `'1'`, for example, is represented by the numerical value 49. To have an alphabetical conversion (i.e. convert `'1'` to `1`), take a look at [std::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string), or, if you're working with c-style strings, at [itoa](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/).